# How to find out Grants given to a stored proc in Sybase IQ

Tags: sap-iq

I am using Aqua Studio to connect to my Sybase IQ database, for some reasons i am unable to view the SP in navigation window of Aqua Studio but i am able to get the SP description using system table SYS.SYSPROCEDURE. Now i also want to see the grants given on this SP. I tried to get this from some systems tables (like SYS.SYSCOLAUTH) but could not get anything.

Can anyone suggest something ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can't understand exactly what grants do you need to find and what things you're unable to do in AquaData. But did you read [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1260/html/iqapg/Uinfo.htm) reference?